# what is difference between Arraylist and ArrayListBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I am trying to learn concurrent package but i have question/doubt about
what is difference between `Arraylist` and `ArrayListBlockingQueue`?

Can somebody explain me.

Comment: didn't google explain it to you? first try it please.

Comment: try to search before ask a new question

Comment: The javadocs will provide you with an answer.

Comment: Er, does `ArrayListBlockingQueue` even exist in the standard Java library? I'm only aware of `ArrayBlockingQueue`, and Google doesn't turn up anything about an `ArrayListBlockingQueue`...

Comment: if you have been find any satisfied ans then pleas share with me.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList` is basically an ordered collection of objects that can grow in size indefinitely. You can always add elements to it. It is not a thread-safe structure.

`ArrayBlockingQueue` is basically a queue whose capacity cannot be increased after creation. If one thread tries to insert an element while the queue is full, the operation blocks, waiting for an element to be polled by an other thread.

Answer (score -3):

ArrayListBlockQueue is a block Queue. the format of it's inner is array list.it will be used when using blocking queue
ArrayList is a Lish. the format of it's inner is an array object.